# The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST. Laravel + react deplo

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, deployment

I got this problem when I deployed a Laravel app:

> The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST.

But on the route I use the method `POST`

```php
Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
```

Comment: The error is saying that, whoever trying to call your route, is using `GET` instead of `POST`, it is a pretty common error, google it and you will find thousands of errors like this, all related to human error...

Answer (score 0):

It's all because you have set it as a post method but requested a get method. I guess this line

```
Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
```

Is located in api.php file. And if you want to use it, you should change the request to a `POST` not a `GET`

since you're using a react.js maybe you wanna do something like this inside your js

```js
fetch("localhost:8000/api/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
  headers: {
  // give csrf token, link down below
  }
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  // do something
})
.catch(error => {
  // Handle any errors here
});
```

any documentation related to the csrf token can be found in [laravel's docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf)